# Decomposition of subgroup in $S_{8}$ as the direct product of cyclic subgroups

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I found the following question in my lecture notes:

Consider the following subgroup of $S_{8}:\ \langle(1 5 7 2 4 8), (1 4 7)(2 5 8)(3 6)\rangle$. Decompose this subgroup as the direct product of cyclic subgroups.

I was hoping someone could guide me through the process of finding the direct product of the cyclic subgroups. I am not interested in "the answer", but in the intuition that's needed to solve the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to find the order of the subgroup? On MSE there are many answers how to do this (did you search already?)

Comment: Let's call the permutations $x$ and $y$. You can check that $xy=yx$, so they generate an abelian group. They both have order $6$, but $x^2=y^2$ so they do not generate disjoint subgroups.